# Try to separate a loop result

Tags: php

I'm making a poll, and I have a php script to get the percents of the number voted for that poll option. When i run a query I just keep getting 0 for the options. How can I make it so that each $val1 has a different number according to the row total in the database for?

For example: poll option 1 has 1 vote, poll option 2 has 1 vote, poll option 3 has 0 and poll option 4 has 0. and the query would output 50 option one and option 2 and 0 for option 3 and four.

My code

```
       $poll = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM home_poll ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
   $option_sql = $db->query("SELECT total FROM home_polls_option WHERE poll_id = '" . $poll['id'] . "'");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($option_sql)) {
            $val1 = $row['total'];
        }

$poll_votess = $db->query("SELECT * FROM home_polls_vote WHERE poll_id = '" . $poll['id'] ."'");

$val2 = $poll_votess->num_rows;

$res = round ($val1 / $val2 * 100);
 $options1 .= ' <script>

    var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: ' . $res . ',
                color:"#F7464A"
            },
            {
                value : ' . $res . ',
                color : "#46BFBD"
            },
            {
                value : ' . $res . ',
                color : "#FDB45C"
            },
            {
                value : '. $res.',
                color : "#949FB1"
            }

        ];

var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);

</script>';
```

Database :

home_polls_vote: http://prntscr.com/2vd1lt
home_polls_option: http://prntscr.com/2vd1k7

Comment: my html: http://prntscr.com/2vd1vx

Comment: aaaaand sql injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection . You have created a nice attack vector for your database by that.

Comment: why don't you use mysql join query to obtain the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In while loop you have took in `$val1` just latest row value and because it is 0 votes, you got everywhere 0. You need to put it into array and later on use `$res` as array also so you can print different values down there in your script.

EDIT:

You can try something like this. First fetch total number of votes, then put percent in result in while loop.

```
$poll = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM home_poll ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$option_sql = $db->query("SELECT total FROM home_polls_option WHERE poll_id = '" . $poll['id'] . "'");
$poll_votess = $db->query("SELECT * FROM home_polls_vote WHERE poll_id = '" . $poll['id'] ."'");

$number_of_votes= $poll_votess->num_rows;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($option_sql)) {
    $res[] = round ($row['total'] / $number_of_votes * 100);
}

$options1 .= '<script>

    var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: ' . $res[0] . ',
                color:"#F7464A"
            },
            {
                value : ' . $res[1] . ',
                color : "#46BFBD"
            },
            {
                value : ' . $res[2] . ',
                color : "#FDB45C"
            },
            {
                value : '. $res[3].',
                color : "#949FB1"
            }

        ];

var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);

</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql it'self for calculation this will avoid many lines of code and ease to process

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

```
$sql = " SELECT ROUND(COUNT(hpv.id)/hpo.total * 100) AS res 
            FROM  home_polls_option AS hpo
            JOIN home_polls_vote AS hpv ON hpv.poll_id = hpo.poll_id
            WHERE hpv.poll_id=$poll ['id']
            GROUP BY hpo.value";
```